# How do I get a for-loop to run for each element in an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a code which does a fit to a Gaussian sample with added noise 100 times over, and then finds the standard deviation of the fitted stdv of the samples. I want the code to run over 100 different values of the noise stdv and save the results in a new array. My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

points = 100
noise_stdv1 = np.linspace(0.0, 0.1, points)
G_stdv = []
G_initial = [0.0, 1.0]
range1 = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, points)

def gaussian(x, mu, sigma):
    return np.exp(-(x - mu)**2 / (2*(sigma)**2))

for i in noise_stdv1:

   noise1 = [np.random.normal(0.0, 0.1, points) for i in range(points)]
   G_sample = [gaussian(range1, 0.0, 1.0) for i in range(points)]
   G_noise = [G_sample[i] + noise1[i] for i in range(points)]
   G_param1 = [curve_fit(gaussian, range1, G_noise[i], p0 = G_initial) for i in range(points)]
   G_param2, G_covar = map(list, zip(*G_param1))
   G_param_stdv = [i for _,i in G_param2]
   G_stdv.append(np.std(G_param_stdv))
```

Where G_stdv should be the saved standard deviation for each iteration of the for-loop. However, when I run the code the G_stdv array only consists of 100 results from the last element in noise_stdv1, not one for each element. Could anyone help me with how to get the for-loop to correctly run once for each element in noise_stdv1?

Comment: each iteration np.std only generate one data point.

Comment: Use a variable other than the one from your for loop in your list comprehensions

Comment: What do you mean? Which variable should I use in the for-loop instead?